# How to access variables used in "git submodule foreach" from outside?

Tags: bash, git, git-submodules

How to recurse into all submodules and save the info to an array? that array should be accessible from outside of `git submodule foreach`, in the below example, I am trying to save all the paths which has `foo` in it.

```
$ declare -a paths
$ git submodule foreach --recursive '[[ "$name" = *"foo"* ]] && \
 ( echo $path; paths+=($path) ) || true'
Entering 'bar-1'
Entering 'foo-1'
foo-1
Entering 'foo-2'
foo-2
Entering 'foo-8'
foo-8
Entering 'foo'
foo
Entering 'baz'
$
$ echo ${paths[@]}
$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git submodule foreach` runs in a sub-shell.  This means there is no direct way to affect the parent shell, and that, in turn, means you need to affect the parent shell *indirectly*.

There are any number of ways to do this, but a simple one is to write to a file, then use `source` or `.` to read the file.  Given your syntax above, you are presumably using bash, so:

```
git submodule foreach --recursive '[[ "$name" = *"foo"* ]] && \
     ( echo $path; echo "paths+=($path)" >> /tmp/paths ) || true'
source /tmp/paths
rm /tmp/paths
echo ${paths[@]}
```

Another way to do this is to `eval` the output of the foreach, but this is trickier since you then have to be careful with *all* output.  There's a handy trick with `exec` for this, to redirect various file descriptors:

```
exec 1>&3
eval $(command)
```

where `command` expands (via alias or shell function, or script, or whatever) to:

```
command() {
    exec 4>&1 1>&3 3>&-
    echo now we can print normally
    echo var=value 1>&4 # this is a directive for the "eval"
}
```

The outer `3>&1` makes a copy of stdout for the inner `command`, which then moves its fd 1 to fd 4, moves 3 to 1, and closes 3.  Now the inner command's stdout is the same as the outer stdout, while fd 4 is where the items to be `eval`-ed go.

Answer (score 0):

Write the values as assignment statements to a temp file. Source the temp file.